# A Question about the _Mathematics Student Journal_

Tags: reference-request

I was reading Anneli Lax's excellent monograph on Linear Algebra and she refers to learning methods to yield $f_n$ (the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number) *directly* (without first calculating $f_i \forall i<n$).

She says that this was also done by Paul Garrett (a high school student then) in his paper *Matrix Eigenvalues: Characteristic Values* in the May 1971 issue of *The Mathematics Student Journal*.

I believe this journal was published by the NCTM in the US. But I am not able to find it (perhaps I am not looking well enough on JSTOR). Do you know if this journal was discontinued or replaced by some other journal? Are its archives available somewhere?

PS: Was it the same [Paul Garrett](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/12291/paul-garrett)?

Comment: I have a photocopy of that paper (and many others from the same journal), but I don't have time to look for it now. If you're interested, I'll look for it later and make a scan of the paper (my email address is in my MSE profile if you want to send me an email to reply to). I don't know if it's the same [MSE Garrett](https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=11350) ([here also](https://www.proquest.com/openview/20bccf441598e79d1f9eb9f0220de285/1)), but the publication year is definitely consistent (allowing for the fact that May 1971 could be 1-2 years after it was actually written).

Comment: Yes, that was me! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Mathematics Student Journal" was a scholarly journal published in United States focused on Education (ISSN is 0095-7089). It began in 1954 and ceased publication in 1973. It was continued by "Mathematics Student" which ceased publication in 1981.

This [web-page](https://archive.org/details/pub_mathematics-student) in the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/) is about a collection of microfilms of the journal published between 1970 and 1981.
[Here](https://archive.org/details/sim_mathematics-student_1971-11_19_1/mode/2up) I found the first page of the the November 1971 issue. I was not able to retrieve the May issue of the same year.